# adding url parameter to html page

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have an html file named `abc.html` which contains two input elements

```
<input type="text" id="txt"></input>
<input type="button" id="btn"></input>
```

The button simply displays the textbox value.

1. Is there any way that I can add some url parameter so that I can specify the value of textbox.
2. Can the button onclick be automatically initiated when the page loads.

Inshort I want to give url parameters such that when I open the url I just see the value that I passed in the parameter. Button `onclick` event should also be initiated.

Comment: Did you similar to google [search page](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=auto+text) ?

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle of what you have done till now?

Comment: Maybe [HERE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#captured-parameters)

Comment: trigger event: use fireEvent or dispatchEvent. As for getting HTML URL parameters, refer to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript/2880929#2880929

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way that I can add some url parameter so that I can
>   specify the value of textbox.

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
  return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null
}
```

Now to get url parameter

```
var param = getURLParameter("paramName");
```

To set value of textbox

```
var elem = document.getElementById("txt");
elem.value = param;
```

> Can the button onclick be automatically initiated when the page loads

```
window.onload = init;
function init() {
var button = document.getElementById("btn");
button.onclick = handleButtonClick;
}
function handleButtonClick() {
alert("Button has been clicked");
}
```

Hope it helps. Let me know if you have any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You will use this code to click button automatically.

> ```
> $(document).ready(function(){
>    document.getElementsById("btn")[0].click();
> });
> ```